# Getting different number of AWS instances depending on how I count

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, python, boto

I am calculating my total number of reserved instance on the basis of `instance_type` and I'm storing this in a dictionary by `instance_type` as a key.

Firstly, I'm finding my all reserved instances by `get_all_reserved_instances()`, then for each instance returned by this, I do this:

```
if each.state != 'retired':
 key = str(each.instance_type)
 res_count[key]+=each.instance_count
```

I'm also calculating total number of instances on the basis of `instance_type`. Firstly, I'm finding my all instances by `get_all_instances()` and then for each `instance_type` I do this:

```
if each.state == 'running':
 key = str(each.instance_type)
 all_count[key]+=1
```

Now for one instance type it returns:

`all_count = 17`

`res_count = 19`

How's it possible that `res_count` is greater than `all_count`?
`res_count` can be equal to `all_count`, if there is no `ondemand` instance, but why this is greater than `all_count`? 
can a non-retired instance also be not running ? if it is,then i think this is case for this difference.

Is there any fault of using state or is there another reason?

Comment: Log into the console, click on Reserved Instances, and see how many you've actually reserved. You can absolutely have more reserved instances than "all instances"--just because you reserved an instance doesn't mean that you're actually making use of the reservation.

Comment: it means we reserved instances, but we are not using them. that's why it is showing reserved instances more than total instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can a non-retired instance also be not running?

- Yes, an AWS EC2 instance can be in multiple states in addition to `running`. Per the latest official documentation in this link [Instance Life cycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html), there is no `retired` state but the line `each.state != 'retired'` in your code will pull all the reserved instances nevertheless.

How's it possible that res_count is greater than all_count?

- You have instances in a state other than running.